# How to add a radius to a marker in Google-Maps-for-Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

i am using the Google-Maps-for-Rails gem and I am now trying to display circles.

My Model "Place" consists of:

- longitude
- latitude
- radius
- etc

I have no problem to display markers:

```
# Controller: @markers = Place.all.to_gmaps4rails
gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @markers})
```

Unfortunately it doens't include :radius => ..
I also know that circles can be displayed like:

```
gmaps(
"circles" => { "data" => '[
                         {"longitude": -122.214897, "latitude": 37.772323, "radius":1000000}
                         ]',
})
```

Is there any way to include the radius attribute in the markers hash ? Like:

```
gmaps("circles"     => { "data" => @markers })
```

Probably something like:

```
Place.all.each |place| place.merge!(:radius => 1000) ...
```

would do, but I think there may be a nicer solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic behind markers and circles is really different.

In your controller

```
@markers = Place.all.to_gmaps4rails
@circles = Place.all.map{|p| {:longitude => p.longitude, :latitude => p.latitude, :radius => p.radius}}.to_json
```

In your view:

```
<%= gmaps({ "markers" => {"data" => @markers},
           "circles" => {"data" => @circles}
          }) %>
```

Or if you don't need `infowindow` or other features, you could simply do:

In your controller

```
@circles = Place.all.map{|p| {:longitude => p.longitude, :latitude => p.latitude, :radius => p.radius}}.to_json
```

In your view:

```
<%= gmaps({ "markers" => {"data" => @circles},
           "circles" => {"data" => @circles}
          }) %>
```

Comment: answer improved with better query