# When adding circles to a gmaps4rails, I get an error that reads: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'circle.serviceObject.getBounds'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

My objective is to add circles in place of markers to show the general area of the location  of the each tool in the Tool model.  I was able to add circles based on other answers on SO, however using the following code I get the error in the title of this question.

In my controller:

```
def index
  @tools = Tool.all
  @json=Tool.all.to_gmaps4rails

  @circles = Tool.all{|t| {:longitude => t.longitude, :latitude => t.latitude, :radius =>"1000" }}.to_json 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @tools }
  end
end
```

In my view file:

```
<%= gmaps({ "markers" => {"data" => @circles}, "circles" => { "data" => @circles} }  ) %>
```

The JavaScript error directs me to the line 401 in the gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js file:

```
  this.boundsObject.extend(circle.serviceObject.getBounds().getNorthEast());
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Is this a JavaScript, Rails error, or something else? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: It looks like it is a javascript error.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely a javascript error, I've updated the question with more information.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you written any code Javascript as well? When does this error occur? On page load? What Javascript is executed on page load?

Comment: No I haven't written any code whatsoever.  This error occurs on page load.

Comment: Your js does not respect the format expected by the gem. See: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Circles

Comment: @apneadiving thanks for coming to the rescue!  Actually, I've looked at a previous answer you left and was wondering where I went wrong implement your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5723080/1658759

Comment: The answer is outdated, the doc rules :)

Comment: @apneadiving, Good thing I re-asked the question, in that case, what would be a good way to make sure that each tool location has its own circle with radius 1000m?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

put a break put in `this.boundsObject.extend(circle.serviceObject.getBounds().getNorthEast());`

and print our the circle

if i am not wrong @circle in rails is not format correctly

```
  @circles = Tool.map{|t| {:longitude => t.longitude, :latitude => t.latitude, :radius =>"1000" }}.to_json
```

it should be map instead of all to map all the array and print out in json